# How do I force specific permissions for new files/folders on Linux file server?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, file-sharing, file-permissions

I'm having an issue with my install of Ubuntu 9.10 (file server) and its samba permissions. Logging in and reading works fine. However, creation of new directories by users restricts access for other users. For instance, if Bob (Windows user who maps the drive) creates a folder in the directory, Jane (Mac user that simply smb mounts) can read from it, but can't write to it -- and vice versa. I then must go CHMOD 777 the directory for everyone to be happy. I've tried editing the "create/directory mask", and "force" options in the smb.conf file but this doesn't seem to help.

I'm about to resort to CRONTABing a recursive chmod routine, although I'm sure this isn't the fix. How do I get all new items to always be 777? Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this ever-occurring situation?

Best

Comment: User groups and other native permissions, don't chmod 777.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I typically use SAMBA's native functionality for permissions and groups management on shares.  For example..

```
force user=user1
force group=sharedgroup
create mask=775
```

You would specify these settings under the share.  Be certain to reload SAMBA after the configuration change, which could be done via the init script.

Comment: Yet the post says he did that and it didn't work....

Comment: Then he did it wrong.  It works.

Comment: I'm not sure what's up.  I've tried it manually and via Webmin to no avail.  Perhaps my group choice of group is wrong?  I've tried using "users" as well as various manually created groups, of which all have been made members.  Regardless of what I do, users can't manipulate anything they didn't place themselves.  The only "solution" is to have all users log in (or mount) as GUEST which produces confusion.

Comment: SAMBA uses a combination of filesystem permissions and settings within the configuration.

If users aren't on a `write list` or otherwise allowed to write in the share configuration, it will not work.

If the user that SAMBA runs at is unable to access the directories, it will not work.

Users should be members of the appropriate group, the directories and files should be owned by that group, and have the writable bit set for the group.  You can check the SAMBA logs as well.

Comment: Yes, and to my knowledge I've done this.  After reading repsonses I know *what* needs to be done (and I feel that I've done it), but apparently I'm missing something.  Can you point me to a bit of info on something specific?  Thanks, btw.

Comment: Does the user writing have permissions on the local filesystem as well as via the SAMBA configuration?  The user would need to be owner or member of the group with permissions to write as well as be on the write list, for example.

Comment: I've been looking for a long time for this! Thanks! :) It's working as expected.

Comment: I've been trying to do this forever, too.  This still works and is particularly useful on a NAS running transmission-daemon as one user but you occasionally forget and make edits over samba as a different user.

Comment: This solution should work, and used to (~20 years with Samba here) but now, on one particular setup (Win7 to Raspbian (freshly apted + 4.x kernel), it just doesn't, like with the OP 7 years ago. Here everything gets created by root, with 777. No clue in the logs. It's late at night here, and I'm sure I'm missing something ridiculously obvious, but... what? (There seems to be a wicked catch here, as it has apparently happened to others, too, before.)

Comment: Finally figured it out: https://serverfault.com/a/887362/167625

Answer (score 2):

Set the permissions on the directory to be 2777, like this:

```
chmod 2777 /shared/dir
```

This causes all files and folders under the '/shared/dir' directory to inherit the permissions of the top directory, in this case 777.

Afterwards, do this to make sure all files have the proper permissions:

```
chmod -R 777 /shared/dir
```

Comment: About the only situation where publicly writable is acceptable is with `/tmp`.

Comment: Yeah, probably better to use 774 or even 770, depending on the situation. But, he asked how to make them all '777', so I just used that in my example.

Comment: Yes, but how do I ensure that all future files copied to that directory over the network receive the same permissions regardless of their initial permissions?  I have no problems when manually doing it, I simply want it automated.

Comment: This does not work.  The setgid flag for folders sets the group of new files and folders, not permissions, and running chmod all the time is not acceptable.  I need a solution that is not related to samba, for Steam on Linux so I can share library between users.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but I recently had a similar issue and here's how I solved it:

```
[share]
security mask = 0770
create mask = 0770
force create mode = 0660
comment = Samba share for IT
path = /raid/share
browseable = YES
guest ok = no
write list = root, @"DOMAIN+it_nfs"
force group = DOMAIN+it_nfs
```

This ensures that users have to be in the "it_nfs" security group in AD, all files will be written with group "it_nfs," and all files will be written with at least 0660 and at most 0770 perms.  Forcing the group ID ensures that anybody in that group can read/write the files on the share.  Otherwise you end up with situations where a file written as bob:bob can't be written by charlie:charlie, even though both of them are in "it_nfs".

Answer (score 0):

From the comments of the accepted answer, it actually didn't solve OP's problem, and neither did the other answers, if OP happened to have the same problem as I did:

*Having the share on an NTFS/FAT partition.*

Remember this when plugging your desktop disk to a NAS for sharing your family albums: fs **mount params** for user, group, create modes etc. **override** whatever is configured for Samba! ;)

(E.g. in my case, regardless of `smb.conf` everything was created by `root`, with `777` – as per the fstab `defaults` for the NTFS fuse mount...)