# How can I give permissions to linux user to execute chown and chmod commands for specific directory?

Tags: linux, security, redhat

I have a linux server RHEL 8. This server has a linux user called 'john'. This user doesn't have permissions to apply sudo as root.

I wish to give to john user permissions to execute chmod and chown commands for /opt/tomcat directory and all its content. Not for other directories. John user shouldn't execute chown command for files from wildfly directory, for example.

How can I achive that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force specific permissions for new files/folders on Linux file server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/158536/how-do-i-force-specific-permissions-for-new-files-folders-on-linux-file-server)

Comment: Sounds like an "X-Y Problem" to me.  
File ownership shouldn't /need/ to be changed - that it does suggests that your access controls and/or permissions /elsewhere/ are just plain wrong.  
Group-level permissions and Sticky Bits may be your friends here.

Comment: Only root (or to be more precise: anyone with CAP_CHOWN capabilites) can `chown`. What I would do is 1. ask if you really need this or you have another problem (@Phill above also suggested this) and 2. if you really need this write a special purpose script that solves your chown'ing and allow sudo exactly for that script and that user.

Comment: Unfortunatlly, it doen't for How do I force specific permissions...

Comment: Delegating `chown`/`chmod` permissions is a dangerous game for user controlled folders and will most likely lead to a privilege escalation. Properly state your real, underlying issue rather than the intended workaround.